# What is the functional derivative with respect to a derivative?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, functional-derivatives

Does the following *functional derivative* can be evaluated?
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi(x))} \int d^4y F(y) \partial_\nu\partial^\nu\phi(y)$$
I am trying to find the equations of motion of a classical field with a Lagrangian that has the form:
$$\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi)+\int d^4y F(y) \partial_\nu\partial^\nu\phi(y)$$
Is the *conventional* form of E-L equation valid here:
$$ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi(x))}- \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi}=0$$
Or is a *new* form necessary due to the dependence on the second derivative inside the integral of the Lagrangian?

Answer (score 1):

You can just partially integrate the double derivative to get $-\partial_\nu F \partial^\nu \Phi$. Or use a definition for the functional derivative analog to the usual derivative, where you'd, in this case, replace $\partial^\nu \Phi(y)$ by the delta-distribution of $\delta(x-y)$.